# Play Youtube HDR videos without any issue

Tags: catalina, google-chrome, youtube, hdr

While playing Youtube HDR videos on Chrome, bright colors are abnormally too bright and causes a loss of details in bright areas. For more information about this issue you can see the posts below:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/mcselq/color_problem_on_macbook_pro_16_2019/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/jk7g8u/chrome_macos_not_displaying_youtube_hdr_content/

Is it normal for everybody? I there any way to overcome this problem? As of now I can't see any other way to play Youtube HDR content on Mac. There's no Youtube app on Mac, and Safari does not support HDR.

Comment: Try it on Safari. Chrome is notorious for ignoring colour profiles. [I'n the meantime, let me find my answer on another stack explaining how to enable them…] Safari *does* support HDR video, if your Mac & OS is new enough. https://support.apple.com/HT210980

Comment: I found some mumbling on the interweb that this is possible with latest Chrome & Big Sur, not Catalina. No definitive source, just a few users mentioning it.

Comment: ah, my 'other answer' was on how to enable it in Firefox, not Chrome.

Comment: Anything possible on catalina ?